# android values folder item naming convention

Tags: android, android-resources, android-styles

I've come across some android native code where the strings.xml in android would be named strings-global.xml and likewise the styles.xml would instead be called styles-global.xml.  how is android identifying this ? what does it mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming of files within the `values\` folder is arbitrary. What resources the file provides is defined by the contents of the file itself, not the name. Which resources are used in a given configuration is determined by qualifiers on the `values\` folder (e.g. `values-fr`), not the file name.

You could even mix and match resource types in a single file if you really wanted to, though I recommend following convention.

From the Providing Resources documentation for the `values\` folder:

> Because each resource is defined with its own XML element, you can
>   name the file whatever you want and place different resource types in
>   one file. However, for clarity, you might want to place unique
>   resource types in different files.

In this case, it sounds like the developers discovered that their `styles.xml` was getting too large and/or they found that they had a few distinct categories of styles that they wanted to separate, and thus put them in different files to keep them more organized.